# Formalise the following requirement in propositional logic using suitable propositions for the component statements

Tags: formal-languages, formal-verification, formal-methods, formal-semantics

The process a or process b enters the critical section, but not at the same time. If this happens (i.e. they enter the critical section simultenously), an interrupt will be executed.

p = process a

q = process b

r = critical section

operator ∨ = or

operator → = implication

my answer :

**(p ∨ q)  → r**

Is this correct or have I Done something wrong? I am trying to understand propositional logic.

Comment: Is it just plain propositional logic you want/have to use, or a temporal logic like LTL? Is this the complete task description?

Comment: Your answer seems to translate into English as "process a or process b only if critical section", which seems to be lacking three verbs.  In propositional logic, variables (p, q, r) represent *propositions*, i.e. statements, things that can be true or false.  You probably want to try with atomic units which are statements, not noun phrases.